# Как перегрузить конструктор с ArrayList, но разными дженериками

Tags: java, arraylist, generics, конструктор

требуется два конструктора класса, у обоих в параметрах тип переменных - динамический массив, но с разными дженериками, IDEА ругается, как осуществить вызов конкретного конструктора в зависимости от <типа данных> переданного в конструктор, можно просто дописать в конструктор еще какой-нибудь int который не имеет смысловой нагрузки, но возможно есть более правильное решение без костылей

```
public Main (ArrayList<String> name){}   
public Main (ArraList<SecondClass> second){}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Правильным решением будет использование фабричных методов вместо прямых конструкторов. Конструктор сделать приватным и реализовать логику выбора нужного листа.

```
private Main(ArrayList<String> name, ArraList<SecondClass> second){
     // ...
}

public static createMainFromStringList(ArrayList<String> name) {
    // ...
    return new Main(name, null); // вместо null можно пустой лист
}

public static createMainFromSecondClassList(ArrayList<SecondClass> second) {
    // ...
    return new Main(null, second); // вместо null можно пустой лист
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с дженериками в Java в том, что в рантайме их типы стираются, для компилятора сигнатуры этих методов одинаковые.

Сразу в лоб вижу, как минимум, два варианта решения:

1. Заменить список на массив:

   ```
       public Main (String[] name){}   
       public Main (SecondClass[] second){}
   ```
2. Определить кастомные типы:

   ```
   class FirstList extends ArrayList<String> {
       [...]
   }

   class SecondList extends ArrayList<SecondClass> {
       [...]
   }
   ```

И использовать так:

```
public Main (FirstList  name){}   
public Main (SecondList second){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Предпочтительней использовать интерфейс, а не его реализацию. Поэтому советую поменять `ArrayList` на `List`.
Так же не понятно что мешает параметризировать свой класс. Выглядеть будет так:

```
class Foo<T> {
    public Foo(List<T> list) {

    }
}
```

При необходимости в параметр конструктора можно добавить `Class<T> clazz` чтоб получить информацию о классе Т.